# Modular Arithmetic with Algebra

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, quadratics

> If positive integer $x$ satisfies $x^2 - 4x +56 \equiv 14\pmod{17}$, find the minimum value of $x$.

---

I have a solution that uses the quadratic formula, but I'm looking for more elegant ways to arrive on the answer ($10$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can't get much simpler than $\,(4\pm\sqrt{\color{#c00}1)}/2 \equiv \{3,5\}/2\equiv \{20,22\}/2\equiv 10,11,\ $ since the discriminant is $\,(-4)^2-4(8)\equiv -16\equiv\color{#c00}1\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

$x^2-4x+42\equiv0\bmod17$

$x^2+13x+42\equiv0\bmod17$

$(x+6)(x+7)\equiv0\bmod17$

$x\equiv-6$ or $-7\bmod17$

$x\equiv11$ or $10\bmod17$

Answer (score 1):

This may be more elegant than the quadratic formula, but still uses some simple plugging-and-chugging.

Rearranging gets $x^2-4x+42\equiv 0\pmod{17}$, and changing to vertex form gets $$(x-2)^2+38\equiv 0\pmod{17}.$$

Now, $$(x-2)^2\equiv -38 \pmod{17} \rightarrow (x-2)^2\equiv -4\pmod{17} \rightarrow (x-2)^2\equiv 13\pmod{17}.$$

From here, just plug-and-chug. Since the RHS must be a perfect square along with the LHS, I would just list the positive integers that are $13\pmod{17}$.

$$13, 30, 47, \boxed{64}$$

So $x = 10.$